# How do I take an array of objects and extract bits from those objects to build a new array?

Tags: powershell

I'm not sure if I'm even asking this question the right way or using the right notation, but here's what I want to do.

I've done

```
$matches=$_|Select-String '(?smi)(\d*)\: (.*?)' -AllMatches | Foreach{$_.Matches}
```

Select-String returns type [MatchInfo], and the Foreach sucks out the Matches property of that type which is type [System.Array]

The $matches is an array of [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group] elements for each match found, but what I want is a 2-D array of capture group value results.

That is, I want an array that contains elements like this:

```
$whatiwant=
   ($matches[0].Groups[1].Value,$matches[0].Groups[2].Value),
   ($matches[1].Groups[1].Value,$matches[1].Groups[2].Value),
   ($matches[2].Groups[1].Value,$matches[2].Groups[2].Value),
   ($matches[3].Groups[1].Value,$matches[3].Groups[2].Value),
   ...
```

How can I build this array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use  this:
 http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/New-PSObjectFromMatches-87d8ce87

It takes a regular expression argument, and produces custom PS Objects from the match groups of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way I discovered to do it.  I don't know if there is a better way.

```
$whatiwant=Foreach($_ in $matches) {,@($_.Groups[1].Value, $_.Groups[2].Value)}
```